# stop pending requests

Tags: playframework

I programmatically (curl) made 100s of requests to play. It is now processing the 23rd one. I would like to cancel all pending requests. play is processing pending ones even after a web server restart.

Is there a kill switch to cancel all those pending requests?

scalaVersion: 2.11.6

Answer (score 1):

100s of requests should be handled very quickly (matter of seconds in fact), by Play. Unless you have multiple blocking calls to multiple database endpoints for example.

You mentioned, as well as the "kill switch":

> Play is processing pending ones even after a web server restart

I think the server did not restarted correctly, or not restarted at all. Do the following again:

```
sbt clean compile run // run the app
```

Do your curl command.

Then, figure out which process is running on port 9000 (your app):

```
lsof -i :9000

COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    25521 ...    ...  IPv6   ...    ...  TCP *:9000 (LISTEN)
```

Then you see for the above I'm running my app with the id `25521`. So I do really stop the process by killing it:

```
kill 25521
```

Then if you run the application again, it shouldn't continue with your pending tasks.

You could use the above command as the "kill switch" of your Play application.